# Product Attributes (size, quantity) in Laravel + Voyager

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am actually a beginner and this is my first "big" project.
I am building a web app for a local detergents shop that should allow the users to order a local delivery of the products at home.

I am using **Laravel**, **darryldecode's Cart** implementation and **Voyager** as an admin panel.
Everything was going well until I stumbled upon **product attributes**. I need to allow users to select different product sizes (1lt, 2lt, etc.) and quantity and to have the price updated via AJAX on the product page and in the cart.
I also have to allow the admin to select which sizes are available for each different product.

What should I explore as a solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question! What do you exactly struggle with?

Comment: @Shadow I don't know how to create a size attribute for my products... because each product will have different available sizes.

Comment: So, you will have a many-to-many relationship between products and sizes (multiple products can have the same size and a product can have multiple sizes). The first duplicate shows you how to model this in native mysql, the 2nd one is for laravel.